# Insertion issue in Json Array object mongodb with Nodejs?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I am new to mongodb , I have below Json structure in mongodb ,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d62452a164b51d64b714c2"),
    "folderName" : "Avinash 1234",
    "tag" : "search",
    "ismainFolder" : true,
    "innerFolder" : [ 
        {
            "ismainFolder" : false,
            "foldername" : "Test12",
            "_id" : ObjectId("59d72246e66adf2cfcfdd6e6")
        }
    ],
    "innerFiles" : [ 
        {
            "filelocation" : "",
            "isFolder" : false,
            "filename" : "Penguins.jpg",
            "_id" : ObjectId("59d7223de66adf2cfcfdd6e5")
        }, 
        {
            "filelocation" : "",
            "isFolder" : false,
            "filename" : "Desert.jpg",
            "_id" : ObjectId("59d72ff4e66adf2cfcfdd6ec")
        }, 
        {
            "filelocation" : "",
            "isFolder" : false,
            "filename" : "Hydrangeas.jpg",
            "_id" : ObjectId("59d731dfe66adf2cfcfdd6ed")
        }, 
        {
            "filelocation" : "",
            "isFolder" : false,
            "filename" : "Chrysanthemum.jpg",
            "_id" : ObjectId("59d73252e66adf2cfcfdd6ee")
        }

    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

For innerFiles array i need to insert the Tag field depending on the id ("_id" : ObjectId("59d7223de66adf2cfcfdd6e5")) . I used following nodeJs code but it adding as a new object . Please give me the solution .

```
exports.addTagForSearch = function (req, res, next) {
    var tagDetails = req.body.tagDetails;
    console.log("tagDetails", tagDetails);
    console.log("tagDetails", tagDetails._id);
    Repository.find({ _id: tagDetails._id, }, { innerFiles: { $elemMatch: { _id: tagDetails._id } } },function (err, response) {
        $push: {
                innerFiles: {
                    "tagName": tagDetails.tagname,
                    }
            //"filelocation": tagDetails.filelocation
        }

    }, { upsert: true, new: true }, function (err, post) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        return res.status(200).json("success");
    });
}
```

but above code inserting as a new object , Please give me solution please .

Comment: And why is this question flagged with `PHP` ?

Comment: Check it I added new answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I need to create a database for that I had a `config.js` file . Here is the code

```
module.exports = {
    'secretKey': '12345-67890-09876-54321',
    'mongoUrl' : 'mongodb://localhost:27017/innerFiles'
}
```

Next create a `models` folder and keep this `order.js` in it

```
// grab the things we need
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var folderSchema=new Schema({

    ismainFolder:{
        type:String,
        //required:true,
        default:''
    },
foldername:{
        type:String,
        //required:true,
        default:''
    }

});

var innerSchema=new Schema({

    filelocation:{
        type:String,
        //required:true,
        default:''
    },
    isFolder:{
        type:String,
        //required:true,
        default:''
    },
    filename:{
        type:String,
        //required:true,
        default:''
    }

});

var main= new Schema({
folderName:{type:String},
tag:{type:String},
ismainFolder:{type:String},
    innerFolder:[folderSchema],
    innerFiles:[innerSchema]

},{ strict: false });



var Order= mongoose.model('main', main);

// make this available to our Node applications
module.exports = Order;
```

Next create a `routes` folder and keep this `orderRouter.js` file in it

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Orders = require('../models/orders');
var app = express();

var orderRouter = express.Router();
orderRouter.use(bodyParser.json());

orderRouter.get('/get',function (req, res, next) {
    Orders.find({}, function (err, order) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(order);
    });
})

orderRouter.post('/post',function (req, res, next) {
   Orders.create(req.body, function (err, order) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(400).send('Bad request');
        }
        else{
        console.log('order created!');
        var id = order._id;

        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });
        res.end('Added the order with id: ' + id);
        }  
  });
})

orderRouter.get('/:orderId',function (req, res, next) {
    Orders.findById(req.params.orderId, function (err, order) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(404).send('OrderId not found');
        }
        else{
        res.json(order);
        }
    });
})

orderRouter.put('/addingField',function(req,res){
             //var tagDetails = req.body;
             console.log("tagDetails:"+req.body.subId);
             console.log("tagname:"+req.body.tagname);
Orders.update(
{_id:req.body.mainId,'innerFiles._id':req.body.subId},
{$set:{'innerFiles.$.tagName':req.body.tagname}},
function (err, article) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  res.json(article);
});
});

app.use('/orders',orderRouter);
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
module.exports = orderRouter;
```

Next create a `app.js` file this is the server code

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var config = require('./config');

mongoose.connect(config.mongoUrl);
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
    // we're connected!
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");
});
var orderRouter = require('./routes/orderRouter');
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

// passport config

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/orders',orderRouter);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers
// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.json({
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.json({
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});
app.listen(3000,function(){
console.log("Server listening on 3000");
});
module.exports = app;
```

And run the server as `node app.js`.You can `post` data using this api `http://localhost:3000/orders/post` you need to use `post` method.Here is the sample input example for posting

```
{
    "folderName" : "Avinash 1234",
    "tag" : "search",
    "ismainFolder" : "true",
    "innerFolder" : [ 
        {
            "ismainFolder" : "false",
            "foldername" : "Test12"

        }
    ],
    "innerFiles" : [ 

        {
            "filelocation" : "a",
            "isFolder" : "false",
            "filename" : "Penguins.jpg"

        }, 
        {
            "filelocation" : "b",
            "isFolder" : "false",
            "filename" : "Desert.jpg"

        }, 
        {
            "filelocation" : "c",
            "isFolder" : "false",
            "filename" : "Hydrangeas.jpg"

        }, 
        {
            "filelocation" : "d",
            "isFolder" : "false",
            "filename" : "Chrysanthemum.jpg"

        }

    ]

}
```

and here is the image for it

[image]

After posting data check that your data is stored in db or not.Here whatever the id I am giving in response is `mainId` . For that run this api `http://localhost:3000/orders/get` use `get` method for this. Collect the sub document id which is `subId` in our code.Sample Image for getting

[image]

After this here is the task of adding a new field to sub document for that use this api `http://localhost:3000/orders/addingField` and you need to use `put` method for this.Here is the input example

```
{
"mainId":"59dca6aff968a98478aaaa96",
"subId":"59dca6aff968a98478aaaa9a",
"tagname":"hello"
}
```

And Image for it

[image]

After completion of all these steps check into db.Here is the sample image for 
it 
[image]

That's it. Hope it helps.

Comment: I am glad ...Check the code and observe each and every line in routes...

Comment: Yes , I got the code and thank you for the help . Its working fine .